# Extrair posição de valores em uma matriz no R

Tags: r, matriz

Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
numbers <- c(303, 2107, 35000)
matriz <- matrix(1:90000, nrow = 300, ncol = 300, byrow=T)
```

Preciso da posição dos valores na matriz. Estou tentando com o seguinte código:

```
linha <- function(mat, vetor){
  aux <- which(apply(mat, 1, function(mat) all.equal(mat, vetor)) == "TRUE")
for (r in 1:nrow(matriz)) {  
    for (c in 1:ncol(matriz)) { 
       print(paste("Row", r, "and column",c, "have values of", matriz[r,c]))
  } }}

linha(matriz, numbers)
```

Porém, ele está retornando a posição de todos os 90000 valores.

Alguém sabe me dizer onde estou errando? Ou possui outra sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não estou certo do que pretende com a primeira linha da sua função, mas confira a ajuda para `all.equal`. Juntamente com uso de `apply` para as linhas da matriz, ela provavelmente não está fazendo o que espera. E de qualquer maneira, o objeto `aux` não está sendo usado posteriormente. O que tem são dois *loops* que circulam por todas as linhas e colunas da matriz, e é isso que está sendo exibido.

Para localizar o índice de um valor em uma matriz, pode usar `which` com a opção `arr.ind = TRUE`. Por exemplo:

```
which(matriz == 4, arr.ind = TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,]   1   4
```

Pode usar isso dentro de um *loop* que percorra todos os valores do vetor de números:

```
linha <- function(mat, vetor) {
  for (valor in vetor) {
    rc <- which(mat == valor, arr.ind = TRUE)
    print(paste("Row", rc[1], "and column", rc[2], "have value of", valor))
  }
}

linha(matriz, numbers)
#> [1] "Row 2 and column 3 have value of 303"
#> [1] "Row 8 and column 7 have value of 2107"
#> [1] "Row 117 and column 200 have value of 35000"
```

Se precisa armazenar o resultado, pode usar `*apply` ao invés de um *loop* e unir o resultado em um *data.frame*:

```
resultado <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(numbers, function(x) which(matriz == x, arr.ind = TRUE))))
resultado$value <- numbers

resultado
#>   row col value
#> 1   2   3   303
#> 2   8   7  2107
#> 3 117 200 35000
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigada! Resolveu a minha questão! :D